# TypeError: Using Custom Activation Function while Mixed Precision Enabled?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was trying to use a **custom activation** in **mixed-precision** enabled training pipelines but faced the following error:

```
TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type float16 of argument 'x'.
```

#### Reproduce

Enabling Mixed precision...

```
import tensorflow as tf 

policy = tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.Policy('mixed_float16')
tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.set_policy(policy)
print('Mixed precision enabled')
```

Custom activation...

```
def ARelu(x, alpha=0.90, beta=2.0):
    alpha = tf.clip_by_value(alpha, clip_value_min=0.01, clip_value_max=0.99)
    beta  = 1 + tf.math.sigmoid(beta)
    return tf.nn.relu(x) * beta - tf.nn.relu(-x) * alpha
```

Training...

```
import tensorflow as tf

(xtrain, ytrain), (xtest, ytest) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

def pre_process(inputs, targets):
    inputs  = tf.expand_dims(inputs, -1)
    targets = tf.one_hot(targets, depth=10)
    return tf.divide(inputs, 255), targets

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xtrain, ytrain)).\
    take(10_000).shuffle(10_000).batch(8).map(pre_process)
test_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xtest, ytest)).\
    take(1_000).shuffle(1_000).batch(8).map(pre_process)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
                             
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1),
                                   input_shape=(28, 28, 1), activation=ARelu),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),

            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), 
                                   activation=ARelu),
            tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),

            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=ARelu), 
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', dtype=tf.float32)]) 

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
history = model.fit(train_data, validation_data=test_data, epochs=10)

# ------------------

TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type float16 of argument 'x'.
```

However, without mixed-precision, it works. I understand the problem simply types miss match but where I should look into it?

Additionally, while trying to solve it, I've found that using `tf.keras.mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer` is safe to avoid numeric underflow. Is it something that we should use for mixed-precision training?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution of the above problem is casting your defined **alpha** and **beta** into `float16` rather than casting the input of your activation layer to `Float32`.

DETAILS:

In reality, the main reason for using MP is to reduce the memory footprint observed during training. The method for doing so is by storing the output of the layer in a `FP16`, since memory consumption is dominated by the storage of activations rather than weights. By recasting your layer output to `FP32` in the custom activation function, you are losing these savings and even requiring more memory to train the model compared to using Full precision because 2 copies exist for your activation.

Comment: These days, it's common practice to recast to float32 from the last layer. However, could you please elaborate more on your last statements with source code regarding multiple copies existence? Thanks.

Comment: Concerning recasting your output to float32, this is only done for the last layer. In your case, you are casting all layers output (next layer input) to float32 by `x = tf.cast(x, 'float32')` which is not recommended. 
Regarding multiple copies, since `tf.Gradienttape` is most probably utilized to perform backpropagation, all operations and tensors will be stored to ease the computation of your gradients. This will often result in storing both precisions of your tensors until the backward path is completed. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Just try casting alpha and beta to half precision rather than casting the input x and inspect the peak memory required for a single training step using `tf.print('PEAK MEMORY in GB: ', tf.config.experimental.get_memory_info('GPU:0')['peak'] / 1000000000)`

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, I've to cast the input to `float32`. I'm not sure though whether it's the right way to solve this error.

```
def ARelu(x, alpha=0.90, beta=2.0):
    alpha = tf.clip_by_value(alpha, clip_value_min=0.01, clip_value_max=0.99)
    beta  = 1 + tf.math.sigmoid(beta)
    x = tf.cast(x, 'float32')
    return tf.nn.relu(x) * beta - tf.nn.relu(-x) * alpha
```

Simply by just typecasting to `float32`, it works.

#### Details

However, the fact is, in order to leverage `mixed-precision`, we have to do as follows:

```
# At the beginning ....
policy = tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.Policy('mixed_float16')
tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.set_policy(policy)
print('Mixed precision enabled')
```

and

```
# at the last layer, adding dtype as float 32
tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation=..., dtype=tf.float32)])
```

Honestly, until now I don't know how the `mixed-precision` mechanism works behind. At first, it sets policy `mixed_float16` and cast output activation as `tf.float32`. By this, we couldn't use the custom activation function unless typecasting the input `x` to `float32` which I believe was `float16` for mixed precision.